# Change chracters in String between some other chracters

Tags: java

Here is some HTML code. How can delete whitespaces before each string but not touch the whitespaces inside the tags? 

    `</a>
        </div>
        <div id="main_menu">
          <div id="horizmenu-surround">
            <ul class="menutop level1" >
                                <li class="item101 active root" >
                            <a class="item" href="/ru/"  >
                        <span>`

Comment: Use regex with `String.replaceAll()`.

Comment: Why is it tagged java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `trim()` method.

```
String newString = oldString.trim();
```

Take a look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Because the question is about replacing all trailing spaces at the begining of each line of multiline Java string, you can use as suggested by C.B. in a comment

`String.replaceAll()` with a regexp. See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: but it is only one string

Comment: you have only one string ?